# WF - ActivityExecutionContext in While Activity

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation

I have a SequentialActivity that also contains a WhileActivity. In the while activity I want to call a method from a service - if it returns true I execute a delay activity, otherwise I continue with workflow execution, therefore I need to retrieve the service using the GetService method. How can I access the execution context from the code condition of the while activity? (WF 3.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't and will need to either create a custom activity or put the code in some other function that you can call from a VB expression.